# How can I edit Startup.cs file after publishing project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-hosting

I've published my MVC project and now i need to edit the startup.cs file 
But when i check the published files in the hosting files i only able to see files for Models , Views , Content (css)
But there's no files for this class (Startup) or even the controllers.

is there a way to edit or even find this file without publishing the entire website again ?

Comment: what you want to change in startup.cs file

Comment: @maulikkansara I wrote some lines of code and i need to remove them

Comment: @kingkomand2o then make them corrected in VS and republish the project.

Comment: @TanvirArjel but i made some changes after-publishing from the host-side and i don't want to reset the whole project

Comment: You could use DotPeek (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile the DLL's within the bin folder of your published site. This will certainly give you access to the controllers but i think you will struggle with the Startup.cs file. Also, you cant edit complied dll's (as far as i am aware) so as @TanvirArjel mentioned you would need to republish.